# SQL Server database option tracking

Tags: sql-server

I am in the unique situation of trying to identify who/when made a change to the options on a customer's database. Specifically the change to the Files properties on a database for our product (the initial size of the log file and the autogrowth options to be most specific). Is there a way to either directly or indirectly found out specifically this, or as a whole, any of the meta data changes to a database? I have seen articles about tracking the changes of the database schema, but I was more concerned with the actual properties of the database such as this and basically anything else in the properties screen for the database.

In this instance, the log file size was drastically increased, so I cannot simply look to see the size of the transaction log backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just googling for this here but

[this](http://www.netwrix.com/sql_server_audit_change_reporter_freeware.html) and [this](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/configuration-changes-history-in-sql-server/) looks like it would do it.

The second link shows turning on tracing and viewing configuration changes history.

Comment: Thanks. The second link was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: No problems, I might actually use that myself.